# Is IsolatedStorageFile.CopyFile() an atomic action?

Tags: windows-phone-8, atomic, isolatedstorage

`IsolatedStorageFile.CopyFile()` documents don't really say much about this, so I was wondering if the CopyFile() (and also `DeleteFile()` for that matter) method is an atomic action on the Isolated Storage?

Meaning, can I be sure that when the `CopyFile()` method returns and the execution leaves the Isolated Storage's using() block, the file has actually been copied to the flash memory? And I can in subsequent operations for example delete the original file(s)?

Comment: Do you mean, "is it synchronous"?  Or, "is it thread safe"?

Comment: More of "is it synchronous". But getting details about thread safety would also be interesting to learn more about.

Comment: Okay well first off, if you are using a "using block" then it will be GCed as soon as it returns so for that portion alone you can rest assured that the file has been opened, loaded into flash and closed. Second, you can't run two isolated storage actions at the same time, otherwise the phone throws an exception. So that should also be an indication that they are taking place seperately. Finally, this isn't that hard to test.So I would just try it if you have any concerns.If you continue to have issue checkout the DLL I wrote for Isolated storage http://anthonyrussell.info/postpage.php?name=47

Comment: The above blog post about Isolated Storage was moved to here http://anthonyrussell.info/postpage.php?name=2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`IsolatedStorageFile.CopyFile` is synchronous: after executing this method, if no exception has been thrown, it means the file has been successfully copied. You can then safely delete the original file.

Note that you can directly use [`IsolatedStorageFile.MoveFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.isolatedstorage.isolatedstoragefile.movefile%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) to do both operation (copying the file and deleting the original) at once.